# Finite etale cover of projective line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

If we have a map $f : \mathbb P^1_R \to \mathbb P^1_R$ over $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, with $R$ a commutative ring, which we assume to be etale, then is it possible to characterize $f$?  Must it be an automorphism?  Does it help to assume $R$ is a field or $\mathbb Z$ or …?

I think the analogous question for $\mathbb A^1_R$ would be no because of positive characteristic phenomena.

Comment: Do you assume that $f$ is finite?

Comment: @Jef since $\mathbf P^1_R$ is proper over $R$, the map $f$ is proper as well. Since everything is of finite type, $f$ is quasi-finite, and therefore finite (Tag [02LS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LS)).

Comment: If by a "map" you mean a morphism of schemes, and not  necessarily $R$-schemes, then there other possibilities. Simply take an etale morphism $R\to R$ and base change to $\mathbb{P}^1_R$

Comment: @DonuArapura the post states "over $\operatorname{Spec} R$", i.e. as $R$-schemes.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I guess I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

This is true. First note that $f$ is proper [Tag [01W6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6) (2)] and locally quasi-finite [Tags [03WS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03WS)], hence finite [Tag [02LS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LS)]. Since $f$ is flat [Tag [02GS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GS)] and finitely presented, it is finite locally free [Tag [02KB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KB)]. It suffices to show that $f$ is locally free of rank $1$ by an easy argument (see [here](https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/locally-free-algebras/) for example).

Now if $S$ is a scheme and $\mathscr F$ is a finite locally free $\mathcal O_S$-module, in order to show that $\mathscr F$ has rank 1, it suffices to show that the same holds for $\mathscr F \otimes \kappa(s)$ for all $s \in S$. Thus, we reduce to the case where $R$ is a field, where the result is an easy consequence of the Riemann–Hurwitz formula (alternatively, use some étale Galois theory and a connectedness theorem; see e.g. [here](https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/p%c2%b9-is-simply-connected/)).

**Remark.** The analogous result for $\mathbf A^1_R$ is false, even if you assume a priori that $f$ is finite. Indeed, for $R = \mathbf F_p$ there is an Artin–Schreier cover $\mathbf A^1 \to \mathbf A^1$ given by $x \mapsto x^p-x$.

However, the result for $\mathbf A^1_R$ is still true as long as each connected component of $R$ has a point with residue characteristic $0$ (for example if $R$ is a domain of characteristic $0$, e.g. $R = \mathbf Z$). Indeed, since the rank of a locally free sheaf is locally constant, it suffices to run the argument above for one point in each component.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that when $R = k$ is a field $f$ must be an isomorphism. Indeed, because $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is a smooth curve, we can apply the Riemann-Hurwitz formula to write
$$-2 = -2\deg(f)+\sum_{y \in \mathbb{P}^1_k}(k_y-1) $$
where $k_y$ is the ramification index of $f$ at $y$. Because $f$ is étale, it is unramified, so $k_y=1$ and the sum vanishes. We now read off $\deg(f)=1$ and $f$ is an isomorphism, as claimed.